# JavaScript validation-- onClick

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have the following piece of code which deletes a document when the delete image is clicked

```
<tr> To replace the document, you will need to first delete the current one. 
      <form name="delete_attachment_form" action="apr_attachment.cfc?method=delete_apr_attachment" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="apr_attachment_id" value="#apr_attachment_id#">
        <input type="hidden" name="apr_section_id" value="#apr_section_id#">
        <input type="hidden" name="submit_mode" value="DELETE">
         <input type="image" name="submit" src="images/delete.gif" alt="DELETE"> 
      </form> 
</tr>
```

Now I want to modify this and change the image to a button and put some basic JS validation so that it asks a confirmation message before deleting.

I have this as my code so far

```
<tr> To replace the document, you will need to first delete the current one. 
      <form name="delete_attachment_form" action="apr_attachment.cfc?method=delete_apr_attachment" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="apr_attachment_id" value="#apr_attachment_id#">
        <input type="hidden" name="apr_section_id" value="#apr_section_id#">
        <input type="hidden" name="submit_mode" value="DELETE">
        <input type="button" onClick ="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the current project activities document')"  name="submit" Value="Delete"> 
      </form> 
</tr>
```

But there is no change/effect in the page when I click this button, Can anyone point out whats happening here? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't the button be of type="submit"?

Comment: Where is your eventListener for the `onClick`?

Comment: @DevlshOne Can't you see???

Comment: @BoltBait No, not necessary

Comment: I am sorry but I am fairly new to JS and I have to get this done for a certain task, I am trying to fiddle around with it while I look for a workable solution online

Comment: Even confirm doesn't appear? Turn on js in your browser

Comment: @nicael hole, I see just fine. A `button` event requires some JS to perform a task. Without it, the click will be ignored.

Comment: Are you shown the alert window?

Comment: @DevlshOne `onClick ="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the current project activities document')"`

Comment: When I have this as my code

`<input type="submit" onClick ="confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the current project activities document')"  name="submit" Value="Delete"> ` 

it deleted the doc if either ok or cancel is clicked, is there a way in which I can capture the user click and work accordingly?

Comment: I think BoltBait say true, the button must be of type="submit"

Comment: @DadyFuji No, it mustn't. It *can* be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id="form"` to `<form>`, then

```
<input type="button" onClick ="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the current project activities document')==1){document.getElementById('form').submit();}"  name="submit" Value="Delete">
```

Comment: No, I tried this and the document is not being deleted when clicked ok or cancel.

Comment: If there is more than one row in the OP's table, `<form id="form">` is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

That's where the rest of the JavaScript comes in... or an AJAX call to a PHP file to perform that task for you. May I give you a couple of pointers? First, give that `button` element and ID, say `id="deleter"`. Then, to clean up your inline markup, add this eventListener in your `<head>` section:

```
<script>
    var d = document.getElementById('deleter');
    var f = document.getElementByName('delete_attachment_form');
    d.onClick = function() {
        var yn = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the current project activities document?');
         // Note that the 'confirm' dialog is an obsolete construct
        if (yn) {
            f.submit();
        }
    };
</script>
```

**HTML Markup**

```
<tr>To replace the document, you will need to first delete the current one. 
      <form name="delete_attachment_form" action="apr_attachment.cfc?method=delete_apr_attachment" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="apr_attachment_id" value="#apr_attachment_id#">
        <input type="hidden" name="apr_section_id" value="#apr_section_id#">
        <input type="hidden" name="submit_mode" value="DELETE">
        <input type="button" id="deleter" name="deleter" Value="Delete"> 
      </form> 
</tr>
```

Comment: But the action to delete the document is present in the action element in the <form> tag, how to I use it in the JS script?

Comment: @user3335993 Like that

Comment: One problem I did not mention... if this table has multiple rows, you will need to have UNIQUE IDs for each of the `<button>` elements. So, you may want to suffix them with the `attachment_id`. You'll also then have to use `getElementsById`, which creates a list of HTML objects and select the right one to process.