# JavaScript Handling the onClick return value

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have the following code to delete a document

```
<tr> To replace the document, you will need to first delete the current one. 
  <form name="delete_attachment_form" action="apr_attachment.cfc?method=delete_apr_attachment" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="apr_attachment_id" value="#apr_attachment_id#">
    <input type="hidden" name="apr_section_id" value="#apr_section_id#">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit_mode" value="DELETE">
    <input type="submit" onClick ="confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the current project activities document')" Value="Delete"> 
  </form>
```

But this is deleting the document irrespective the user clicks ok/cancel, I want the document to be deleted only for ok, how should I proceed?

Comment: How's this different from your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23349975/javascript-validation-onclick?

Comment: May be you should read the question completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one-liner edit to your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" onClick ="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the current project activities document')) return false;" Value="Delete">
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, and was easy, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" onClick ="return checkForm()" Value="Delete">
```

JS:

```
function checkForm() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure")) {
        alert("Clicked Ok");
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Clicked Cancel");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked too but Marlo's answer is much more simpler. Thank you.